# How to register callback function that takes ownership

Tags: rust

I'm following vkguide.dev, but trying to implement it in Rust with the `ash` crate.

For some things like freeing GPU-allocated memory, the author uses a Deletion Queue. Here's how I implemented it in Rust:

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct DeletionQueue {
    pub deletors: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut() -> ()>>,
}

impl DeletionQueue {
    pub fn push_deletor(&mut self, deletor: Box<dyn FnMut() -> ()>) {
        self.deletors.push(deletor);
    }

    pub fn flush(&mut self) {
        // reverse iterate the deletion queue to execute all the functions
        for deletor in &mut self.deletors.iter_mut().rev() {
            deletor();
        }
        self.deletors.clear();
    }
}
```

Now at some point in the code I'm using `gpu-allocator` to allocate memory for an image. After allocating from `allocator : gpu_allocator::vulkan::Allocator`, I get a `gpu_allocator::vulkan::Allocation` struct. This allocation has to be freed later with `allocator.free(allocation)`

I want to register this free into the deletion queue like so:

```
deletion_queue.push_deletor(Box::new(|| {
        unsafe {allocator.free(draw_image_allocation).unwrap();}
    }));
```

But this presents a problem: I want to keep using the allocation after registering this deletor, but the closure above takes ownership of the allocation. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Do you also need to use the allocator, and in particular, do you need to free multiple allocations in different deletors?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The allocator survives the call (it's a &self or &mut self call) but yes, I wish to keep using it afterwards. Also yes, I'll be adding other frees with different deletors further down the line, as I progress through the tutorial

Comment: The allocator also has a problem since it will be borrowed mutably. I think `Rc<RefCell>` is the best solution, at least for the allocator.

Comment: and for the Allocation?

Comment: Also note that the closure will need to be `FnOnce`, otherwise it cannot move out of `allocation`.

Comment: If I redefine closures to be FnOnce, I get "cannot move out of `*deletor` which is behind a shared reference"

Comment: For the allocation it is also possible to use `Rc` (possibly with `RefCell`, if you need mutation) with `Rc::try_unwrap()`, but you have to take care to `drop()` existing `Rc`s to the allocation. Or there is another way, that I can post in an answer.

Comment: Use `drain()` for that.

Comment: Thank you! Why does drain work, but into_iter doesn't?

Comment: `drain()` takes a mutable reference, and the vector can be reused afterwards. `into_iter()` consumes the vector.